# How to hide scollbar when not overflowed yet

Tags: html, css

how can I hide the scroll bar if content height of the div doesn't reach its maximum height like for the example below: `400px` and then shows up when the contents reaches or exceeds the height. Thanks!

So far, what I've done is here:

```
 <div class = "divmenu" style = "height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x:hidden">
     <div class = "col-lg-12">
       Content1 <br>
       Content2 <br>
       Content3 <br>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Use `overflow:auto` over the element.`overflow-x will only disable horizontal`

Comment: Isn't what your desribing the default behaviour?

Comment: The problem is OP has used overflow-x hidden by default in his post.

Comment: There are some bugs with different overflows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421966/css-overflow-x-visible-and-overflow-y-hidden-causing-scrollbar-issue

Answer (score 1):

Simply change it to `overflow: auto` - like this:

```
<div class = "divmenu" style = "height: 400px; overflow: auto;overflow-x:hidden">
     <div class = "col-lg-12">
       Content1 <br>
       Content2 <br>
       Content3 <br>
     </div>
 </div>
```

`overflow-x: hidden` can stay if you need it to